# Finding $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ if it exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ exists. Also find the limit.

**Method 1**

$\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ is less than $1$. Therefore, $\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}<\log(x)$. Also, $\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} \geq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in the domain.

Therefore, we have,

$$
0\leq\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}\leq \log(x)
$$ But $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\log(x)=0$.

Hence, by the squeeze theorem,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} = 0
$$

**Method 2**

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta<e^{\varepsilon}-1 \implies\log(\delta+1)<\varepsilon$.

If,

$(x-1)^2+y^2<\delta^2 \implies |x-1|<\delta \implies |x|-1<\delta$

$\implies x<\delta +1$ $ 
(\because$ $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x<0)\implies \log(x)<\log(\delta+1)$,

then,
$$\left|\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}-0\right|
\leq
|\log(x)|< |\log(\delta+1)|<|\varepsilon| = \varepsilon$$

Hence, by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits, $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Are both my methods correct?

Comment: "Also, $\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} \geq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in the domain". $\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} \geq 0$ holds for $x\geq 1$ (the domain is $x>0$ and $(x,y)\not=(1,0)$). You should consider $|\log(x)|$ also in Method 1.

Comment: @RobertZ I see. So should I write $-$log$x$$\leq\frac{(x-1)^2log(x)}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}\leq$ log$x$? Also is the second method correct?

Comment: Better $0\leq\frac{(x-1)^2|\log(x)|}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}\leq|\log(x)|$. Yes, the second method is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have the main idea correct. But there are details that you need to be careful as some of the comments already point out. For instance $\log(x)\ge 0$ is not always true.

Also, your "method 2" would be less cumbersome if you apply continuity of the logarithm instead of trying to solve an inequality in a sharp way to get $\delta$.

---

Eventually, you want to show that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2+y^2} = 0
$$

Here is a short proof.

**Proof.** Observe that
$$
0\le \left|\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right|=
\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\right||\log(x)|
\le |\log(x)|\;.
$$
Also $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}|\log(x)|=0$. Thus by the "squeeze-type" theorem,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{(x-1)^2\log(x)}{(x-1)^2+y^2} = 0\;.
$$

---

I don't see an explicit "squeeze theorem" of the multivariable function version. Though the idea is of course the same. One may write out the detail of $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}|\log(x)|=0\tag{1}$$ as follows.

Let $\epsilon>0$. By continuity of the logarithm (and the absolute value function) at $x=1$, there exists $\delta>0$ so that
$$
|\log(x)|<\epsilon\quad\textrm{whenever}\quad |x-1|<\delta\;.
$$
Now, if $|(x,y)-(1,0)|<\delta$, then
$$
|x-1|<\sqrt{|x-1|^2+|y|^2}<\delta
$$
and hence $|\log(x)|<\epsilon$.

The estimates above could also give you an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the limit.